# How to add a hyperlink to Windows 8.1 Start Screen which will open in Firefox not Internet Explrorer

Tags: firefox, windows-8.1, hyperlink, start-screen

I wanted to add to the Start Screen a tile which will open my mailbox in Firefox. I followed tutorial in which I added the shortcut via `IE->Tools->Pin website....` but the tile from the Start Scren opens in IE not default browser which is Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a tutorial with pictures and everything [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Pin-Firefox-Web-Apps-to-Windows-8-Start-Screen).

In short, create an Internet shortcut in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and then pin it in the Start Screen.